# How to create zoom in effect using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I am trying to create zooming effect using ffmpeg on a video file.

Here is the code I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -filter_complex "crop=(640-t):(480-t)" output.mp4
```

But it is giving me the undefined constant error.

I know crop accepts iw and ih as the constants but is there any constant for time or any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to crop or create a zoom effect? They are not the same thing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used the `n` constant instead.
This worked:

`ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -filter_complex "crop=(640-(n*10)):(480-(n*10))" output.mp4`

Comment: This doesn't work. There's no zooming, just a constant crop of 640x480. The crop filter isn't even timeline-enabled.

Comment: @Gyan is right. This won't give you zoom in effect.

Comment: @gyan I've posted a working filter in another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom by using `zoompan`.

For example this zooms the video by 10% during play.

This should be the full command

```bash
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -t 10 \
    -vf "zoompan=fps=60:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=hd1080:z='if(lte(it,2),it/2*0.2+1,1.2)':d=1,scale=iw:ih" out.mp4
```

Let me break it down (see also the [`zoompan` docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan))

- `zoompan=` the filter used

The following are the options for zoompan, separated by a colon `:`

- `fps=60` the fps used to calculate each frame. Make sure that this is the same as the input (you can check that with `ffprobe in.mp4`
- `z=` the zoom options. This is an expression, calculated every frame.

  - `'if(lte(it,2),it/2*0.1+1,1.1)'` this is the expression used to calculate the zoom at that frame. If the input time is less than 2 seconds, the `z` should be the part of zoom you want at that frame (`it/2`), times the amount of total zoom you would like (`0.1`), plus 1, because it needs to be zoomed. If over 2 seconds, use the end-state of zoom, in this case `1.1`.
- `x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)'` the x and y position where to zoom. Here we use the center position to zoom.
- `d=1` the duration of this frame in amount of frames. We want each frame to last for 1 frame
- `s=hd1080` the output size. Defaults to `hd720`. Make this the same as your input.
- `scale=iw:ih` the scale of the video. Same as `input-width` by `input-height`

Comment: Can you pls explain "end state of the zoom". I have rendered a text as MP4 with FFmpeg that is n seconds long and would like to stretch the zoom over this time. More precisely, about the duration of the input video, however long it may be. But this script only zooms over the first 3 seconds.

Comment: It worked for me. Only caveat, I had to replace `it` with `time` (ffmpeg v2.8.17).
@AndreasSpindler to extend the duration of the zoom, pass your full video duration to `-t`, and remove the conditional `if..` in `if(lte(time,2)`, i.e. let `z='time/2*0.2+1'`

Comment: @AndreasSpindler The end-state of the zoom would be if you zoom by 10%, the zoom is 1.1. If you want to zoom by 20% it'll be 1.2. If you want to zoom twice the size of the video, it'll be 2.